# Traceback (most recent call last) Python Error

Tags: python

## Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alex\Python\Lesson01.py", line 5, in <module>
    print("In 10 years you will be ", a+b, "years old")
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

At the moment I am Learning Python 3 and got this error. What does it mean? I also tried `+` instead of the comma this is also not working :/

Here is the code:

```py
user_input = input("How old are you?\n-> ")

a = user_input
b = 10
print("In 10 years you will be ", a+b, "years old")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I read inputs as numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to print this:

```py
user_input = int(input("How old are you?\n-> "))

a = user_input
b = 10
print("In 10 years you will be " + str(a+b) + " years old")
```

this should work fine

Answer (score 1):

The other answer by [u/Henrik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14375016/henrik) is correct but I would argue some better naming schemes would improve the readability and usefulness of the code...

```
age = int(input("How old are you?\n-> "))

numYears = 10

print("In " + str(numYears) + " years you will be " + str(age+numYears) + " years old")
```

The point of this way is to make the print statement more versatile, also avoid having duplicate variables where it isn't necessary, and to have better variable names.